# Difference between response.body and body in node request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Trying to learn the node [request](https://github.com/request/request) package. Say if I do a post request:

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({url: url, form: {key:'value'}}, function(err,response,body){ /* ... */ })
```

When I check the `response.body.html()` and `body.html()`, they seem to be the same. Is this correct? And also they seem to be both the original page where I send the data from instead of a response page I expected. Why would this happen? When I use python requests package, and post with the same data to the same url, I got different things. Can somebody enlighten what is happening here?

---

*Edit*: the python code that works as expected:

```
import requests
response = requests.post(url, {
    "key": "value",
     // ... there can be other pairs of key-values
})

response.content
```

*response.content* gives me the result I need.

Comment: What do you mean with _" they seem to be both the original page where I send the data from"_? You can't use `request` in a browser, AFAIK.

Comment: @robertklep So the response html is basically the page with the blank form, while I am expecting a different page returned after submitting the form (something like a search result page after you submit the search query in google). I am using it in node (console), not in browser.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to post the equivalent Python code as well.

Comment: Python's `requests` sends some additional headers that Node's `request` doesn't, which may cause the server to return a different response (you can `POST` to `http://httpbin.org/post` to check the differences and try to match the Node version to the Python version to see if it's related to a particular header).

Comment: @robertklep OK. It suddenly works now. The headers are indeed different. There are three keys (Accept, Accept-Encoding, User-Agent) missing. But now I removed them, it still seems to be working. Not sure what I did. Maybe changed the keyword from json to form (I used to post `json: {key: value}`)? Anyway I am glad it's working now. Thanks for the suggestion. It helps a lot.

Comment: `form` is definitely something different than `json`.

Comment: @Psidom Have you learnt the answer to this question by now? I would also love to know what is the difference between response.body and body.